# upload multiple files error in php

Tags: php, html

I create a folder for files.  I am trying to upload multiple file to this new folder but, my code can't upload the array of files.  I could upload one file to the new dir but not multiple.  Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="document_name[]" type="file" multiple/>
    <input name="document_name[]" type="file" multiple/>
    <input name="document_name[]" type="file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

**PHP**

```
$path = 'CreateFolder';

if (!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["document_name"]["name"]); $i++) {


    $upload_dir = 'C:myDir\\' . $path . '\\';
    $document_url = $upload_dir . basename($_FILES["document_name"]["name"][$i]);

    echo $document_url;//test url

    $type_of_document = pathinfo($document_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//any type allow

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document_name"]["tmp_name"][$i], $document_url)) {

        echo 'Uploaded!';
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. <br/>";

    }
}
```

I follow other answers that I found online.  One of those answers suggest me to use 3 different names, okey cool, but I would like to learn to do it using an array and a for loop.

The only thing that I am getting back is

```
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to declare the inputs names as an array when you use `multiple`, one single `input type=file multiple` should suffice.

Comment: Inside your `$_FILES['input_name']` you'll have a field named `['error']`, check it to see what's going on (`echo $_FILES['input_name']['error'];`).

Comment: And this `$upload_dir = 'C:myDir\\' . $path . '\\';` is probably an invalid path.

Comment: @AlanMachado yes it is an invalid path, my contract doesn't allow me to show anything relate to my job, including the path where I am trying to upload something =/, but thanks

Comment: I was referring to the `C:myDir` lacking a slash, only. But I got you, and the other suggestions I made are still valid, you should try it out :)

Comment: are you sure your folder is writeable ?

Comment: @AlanMachado the  `echo $_FILES['input_name']['error'] ` just echo `#4`

Comment: @AlanMachado none of your suggestion works =(...any other suggestion?

Comment: @NanaPartykar windows 7.

Comment: really? why -1?  -_-, would help me more if you edit the question or ask me a question, so we would learn more.

Comment: @AlanMachado got it! the error works at the end and I could see what was happening.  Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your path. I would do it like this:

```
$upload_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path;
```

and `$document_url` :

```
$document_url = $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($_FILES["document_name"]["name"][$i]);
```